# Merge Powershell Output - Get-VM, Get-VHD

Tags: powershell, failover

I would like to export some Server Statistics from a Failover Cluster System.

My plan is to show with the Get-VHD command all VHD used on the VMs on my host.
So I was Trying to use:
`Get-VM | select-object VMID |get-vhd |ft`
This gives me a list the
"ComputerName, Path, VHDFormat,VHDType,FileSize,MinimumSize, LogicalSectorSize, PhysicalSectorSize"
Sadly the ComputerName is not the VMName but just the Name of the Host.
Now when I run the Get-VM command I get the Name and here it is actually the VMName.

Is there a nice way to get the real VMnames in the Output of Get-VHD?
I am fairly new to Powershell and I could not find a solution that worked... Most of the "sniplets" found here did not work at all or did not return the VMname...

Thank you for your suggestions =)

Sorry, I think my Title is not that well described, I was not sure how this funktion is called.

Comment: instead of the nasty plain text output of `Format-Table`, use `Select-Object` and a calculated property. also, take a look at `-PipelineVariable`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could use a ForEach-Object loop and capture the Name property from the `Get-VM` cmdlet. Then go on with `Get-VHD` and combine the output:

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object { 
    $name = $_.Name
    $_ | Get-VHD | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$name}}, *
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: I have tryed the code, seems not to work. What I noticed working with Get-VHD, that it expects the VMID to work properly. As far as I see your Code passes the "Name" to get-vhd? I will try if it is possible to select two propertys. Like: 'Get-VM | ForEach-Objekt {$name = $_.Name, $vmid = $_.VMID ....' ???
p.s. what does the "$_" in the begenning of the 3rd like of you code mean? I dont understand the connection. 
Thanks anyways. Good evening

Comment: @BitCody The `$_` represents a vm from the GetVM cmdlet. The code is piping this object through to the Get-Vhd cmdlet. This will take the VmId property as input according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vhd?view=win10-ps#parameters). You could also do `Get-VHD -VMId $_.VMID`

Comment: @BitCody P.S. I'm not passing `$name` to the `Get-VHD` cmdlet, I store that value in a variable and have the `Select-Object` use that to prepend another column `Name` to the output. What do you mean by _seems not to work_? Error messages?

Comment: By just running the Code I get the message that Get-VHD: c:\Clusterstorage\....\ no VHD File found. and the following:
+     $_ | Get-VHD | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$name ...
+          ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-VHD], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetVHD

I will try to do the changes from your comment below.

Comment: @BitCody dou you get anything if you do `Get-VM -VMName * | Select-Object VMid | Get-VHD` or just errors that no VHD file can be found?

Comment: 'Get-VM -VMName * | Select-Object VMid | Get-VHD' works so far, it outputs more or less the same what my Code does in my first post. Except without | ft.